# Ruby CSV enumeration confusion

Tags: ruby, csv

How come this does not work? The CSV is there and has values, and I have 'require "csv" and time at the top, so good there. The problem seems to be with `csv.each` actually doing anything.

It returns

```
=> [] is the most common registration hour

=> [] is the most common registration day   (Sunday being 0, Mon => 1 ... Sat => 7)
```

If there is any more info I can provide, please let me know.

```
@x = CSV.open \
'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol


def time_target
y = []
@x.each do |line|
    if line[:regdate].to_s.length > 0
        y << DateTime.strptime(line[:regdate], "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").hour
        y = y.sort_by {|i| grep(i).length }.last
    end
end
puts "#{y} is the most common registration hour"
y = []
@x.each do |line|
    if line[:regdate].to_s.length > 0
        y << DateTime.strptime(line[:regdate], "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").wday
        y = y.sort_by {|i| grep(i).length }.last
    end
end
puts "#{y} is the most common registration day \
(Sunday being 0, Mon => 1 ... Sat => 7)"
end
```

making all the 'y's '@y's has not fixed it.

Here is sample from the CSV I'm using:

> ,RegDate,first_Name,last_Name,Email_Address,HomePhone,Street,City,State,Zipcode
>
> 1,11/12/08
>   10:47,Allison,Nguyen,arannon@jumpstartlab.com,6154385000,3155 19th St
>   NW,Washington,DC,20010
>
> 2,11/12/08
>   13:23,SArah,Hankins,pinalevitsky@jumpstartlab.com,414-520-5000,2022
>   15th Street NW,Washington,DC,20009
>
> 3,11/12/08 13:30,Sarah,Xx,lqrm4462@jumpstartlab.com,(941)979-2000,4175
>   3rd Street North,Saint Petersburg,FL,33703

Comment: You need to show a sample of the CSV data you are reading. Do you mean you are using Ruby's CSV gem? If so, show the code that uses it.

Comment: https://github.com/JumpstartLab/curriculum/blob/master/source/projects/event_attendees.csv

Comment: No, embed the minimum amount of sample data into your question so we don't have to chase it down. WHEN that link breaks it will make your question difficult to understand.

Comment: sorry about that, sample is now there

Comment: Is the problem that there should not be a starting `,` in the headers line?

Comment: I'd bet `:regdate` should be `:RegDate`

Comment: I'd say `y = y.sort_by {|i| grep(i).length }.last` is also suspicious looking. `grep` needs to be passed a pattern not the array element and needs a receiver. for eg: ["a","b"].grep(/a/) #=> [a]

Comment: I would start by refactoring with `CSV.foreach`

Comment: the CSV starting with ',' did not cause problems elsewhere, its just that the first column ([0]) that holds the row number, has no title.

Ill look into the grep thing, though there seems to be a problem with any contents.each type of deal. Im redoing some stuff and will get back with update.

Comment: I have tried :regdate and :RegDate, (and manually changing the csv to lowercase), to no avail. Also, symbolizing the headers seems to downcase them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to load your data:

```
def database_load(arg='event_attendees.csv')
  @contents = CSV.open(arg, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
  @people = []
  @contents.each do |row|
    person = {}
    person["id"] = row[0]
    person["regdate"] = row[:regdate]
    person["first_name"] = row[:first_name].downcase.capitalize
    person["last_name"] = row[:last_name].downcase.capitalize
    person["email_address"] = row[:email_address]
    person["homephone"] = PhoneNumber.new(row[:homephone].to_s)
    person["street"] = row[:street]
    person["city"] = City.new(row[:city]).clean
    person["state"] = row[:state]
    person["zipcode"] = Zipcode.new(row[:zipcode]).clean
    @people << person
  end
  puts "Loaded #{@people.count} Records from file: '#{arg}'..."
end
```